# How do you convert RDLC reports created in Visual Studio 2008 to work in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, rdlc, reportviewer

I have looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer.

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to 2017. I was able to install ReportViewer on 2017, however, if I open reports that were created in VS 2008, I am asked to convert to the new version.

Once they are converted, I get the error `Unknown Report Version: 9.0` for every report.

This has occurred with multiple applications and I had to re-create the reports in one application in order for them to work with VS 2017.  Has anyone run into this?

Comment: What version of the reporting assembly are you using? Also is the message displayed in the VS designer or at runtime?

Comment: I am trying to go from 9.0.0.0 to 14.0.0.0.  The message was displaying when I clicked on the rdlc file.

Comment: We have recently upgraded from 10 to 14 and from VS2012 to VS2017 without such issues. You could try to upgrade to VS2012 or VS2015 and then do an  upgrade to VS2017 from there.

Comment: I tried VS2015 and had no luck, different error, will try VS2012 next.  Thanks!